# When developing a gem, do I have to keep installing after I make updates?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am making a gem in the folder:

```
/Users/me/projects/ruby/gems/mygamename/
```

And its layout is like:

```
/Users/me/projects/ruby/gems/mygamename/mygamename.gemspec
/Users/me/projects/ruby/gems/mygamename/mygemname.rb
/Users/me/projects/ruby/gems/mygamename/lib/mygemname/file1.rb
/Users/me/projects/ruby/gems/mygamename/lib/mygemname/file2.rb
```

Now in my other ruby project, I want to reference this gem in my Gemfile so I did:

```
gem 'mygemname', :path => "/Users/me/projects/ruby/gems/mygamename"
```

I know I should be writing tests for my gem to test for functionaly, but I was curious if I could also do integration tests from my other ruby project (where I am referencing it in my Gemfile).

1. Do I have to re-run bundle if I make updates to the gem?  Or does it keep reading from that folder and it will pickup the changes?
2. Any other advise on how I can test it from my other ruby project?

Again I will be writing tests in the gem itself, but wondering how I can do I this way also in case I want to.

Comment: Throw a `raise` in your gem and see if it blows up without re-bundling `:)`. (While re-bundling shouldn't be required, restarting your app might be.)

Comment: didn't seem to work?  I did ```raise "hello"``` and nothing happened.

Comment: actually even recreating the gem didn't work, looks like I have to change the version.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to run `bundle install` only once. Bundler does not cache or package your gem, it points to your folder directly.

Restarting rules are the same as in the main app. If you make changes to views, assets or autoloaded ruby files, they will be reloaded automatically. However, you will have to restart your app if you required some lib files in the app and changed them. By default Bundler will require "lib/mygemname.rb" of gem "mygemname", so this file will not be reloadable.

Answer (score 0):

Gem classes/modules are cached so every time you make a change to your gemfile, you will have to restart your app. 
Also, if you dont update gem version in your gemspec than you dont have to re-bundle. if you update gem version, than you might need to execute `bundle update gemname`

Answer (score 0):

What I typically do when developing a gem is create Gemfile in a directory and work from there. In the Gemfile, I add a reference to my gem using the :path option.

```
gem 'mygemname', :path => '/path/to/my/gem'
```

Then I run bundle install. This way I don't have to keep reinstalling my gem.

Keep in mind that you need to use bundle exec when running my gem.